# How to take values of Jmeter variable in coma separated way

Tags: rest, testing, groovy, jmeter

I'm hitting a rest Api through http GET request in jmeter.
the url is like http://hostName:port/searchParameter=value1,value2,value3

the value1, value2 ... are taken from a file which is like

File.csv
   value1
   value2
   value3

this csv file is not really coma seperated values they are in separate lines.
Now how to achieve this

Comment: Can you please help us with the piece of code that you are using to fetch these values from CSV ?

Comment: i'm using CSV data config from configure element of jmeter

Comment: could you pleas elaborate a little. i.e. Your CSV data set configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JMeter doesn't provide a suitable test element so you will have to go for [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) and some custom scripting.

I can think of using [File.readLines()](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/io/File.html#readLines()) function to read the contents of your file into memory followed by [join()](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Iterable.html#join(java.lang.String)) function to convert the array into a comma-separated string.

The final syntax would be:

```
${__groovy(new File('File.csv').readLines().join('\,'),)}
```

Demo:

[image]

Check out [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-functions-introduction) article to get familiarized with JMeter Functions concept.